# How to yield objects recursively using python generator?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, generator, yield, yield-from

I am writing a generator function which recursively walks through all the child nodes for a given astroid node.

In the example below, `node` is an astroid `functiondef` node.
`node.getchildren()` returns a generator with subnodes in the node.

My goal is to yield every node contained. ( even in the subnode )

```
def recursive_walk(node):
    try:
        for subnode in list(node.get_children()):
            # yield subnode
            print(subnode)
            recursive_walk(subnode)            

    except AttributeError:
        # yield node       
        print(node)

    except TypeError:
        # yield node  
        print(node)
```

Here, if I have commented out the yield statement.
For print statement, I am getting my desired result, but if I yield the node, I am not getting the desired output.

For reproducing this:
 - install astroid

```
import astroid

node = astroid.extract_node('''
def test_function(something): #@
    """Test function for getting subnodes"""
    assign_line = "String"
    ctx = len(assign_line)
    if ctx > 0:
        if ctx == 1:
            return 1
        if ctx > 10:
            return "Ten"
    else:
        return 0
''')
```

Comment: I have this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    node = astroid.extract_node('''
AttributeError: module 'astroid' has no attribute 'extract_node'`

Comment: Strange. See the last section [here.](http://pylint.pycqa.org/projects/astroid/en/latest/inference.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def recursive_walk(node):
    """
    Generator function to recursively walk through a given node.

    Yields every astroid node inside.
    """
    try:
        for subnode in node.get_children():
            yield subnode
            yield from recursive_walk(subnode)

    except (AttributeError, TypeError):
        yield node
```

This does the work.

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively `map` the function to the childs and use `yield from`:

```
def recursive_walk(node):
    # yield the base node
    yield node
    # for each of the recursive calls yield the remaining ones
    yield from map(recursive_walk, node.get_children())
```

In case they have no children it will just yield nothing and continue with the next ones.

Comment: @SrijanSaurav, since you are new, you may consider reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers , Happy coding!

Comment: Sure.

One follow up question: In the output, am getting the base node, and other generator objects, which is not what I need. 

Is there a way to retrieve all the nodes from those generator objects as well, so that I can have just one function which generates all the nodes ?

Comment: you just need to call to `list(recursice_walk(base_node))` to retrieve all of them.

Comment: Output:

`[<FunctionDef.as_html l.2 at 0x7f20e23a7be0>,
 <generator object try_ at 0x7f20e2515a98>,
 <generator object try_ at 0x7f20e2333570>,
 <generator object try_ at 0x7f20e23337c8>,
 <generator object try_ at 0x7f20e23338b8>,
 <generator object try_ at 0x7f20e2333de0>]`

Comment: Also, the generator objects contain other generators for its nested nodes.

Comment: Uhm that is weird, are you using `yield_from`?, you can try `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(recursive_walk(base_node)))`

Comment: using `yield from`
The same changes you suggested.

And with itertools, getting this : `['self',
 'tpl',
 'ctx',
 <Arguments l.2 at 0x7f20e23a7940>,
 <generator object try_ at 0x7f20e22abb88>,
 <Assign l.4 at 0x7f20e23a7780>,
 <generator object try_ at 0x7f20e22aba98>,
 <generator object try_ at 0x7f20e22ab9a8>,
 <Assign l.10 at 0x7f20e23a7710>,
 <generator object try_ at 0x7f20e22ab750>,
 <Return l.11 at 0x7f20e23a7c18>,
 <generator object try_ at 0x7f20e22abc00>,
 <If l.12 at 0x7f20e23a76d8>,
 <generator object try_ at 0x7f20e22ab1b0>]`

Comment: Let me Edit my question and add some more details for you to reproduce.